# Case insensitive Split-String

Tags: string, powershell, split

How is it possible to make `Split-String` case insensitive?

This works fine:

```
$String = '\\domain.net\share\folder\home\bob\stuff'
$String | Split-String -Separator 'home' -Count 2
```

This doesn't:

```
$String = '\\domain.net\share\folder\home\bob\stuff'
$String | Split-String -Separator 'HOME' -Count 2
```

Comment: You are correct, it's a part of the [PowerShell Community Extension](https://pscx.codeplex.com/).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the [`-split` operator](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847811.aspx), which (by default) is case-insensitive:

```
$Count = 2
$Separator = 'home'
$String -split $Separator,$Count
```

As with all other string operators, it comes in an explicitly case-sensitive flavor as well:

```
"ABC" -csplit 'b' # won't split anything
```

---

Beware that `-split` interprets the separator as a Regex pattern. You can force a simple substring match with the "SimpleMatch" option:

```
$String -split $Separator,$Count,"SimpleMatch"
```

The last option only works when the `$Count` is specified, but you can specify a `$Count` of 0 to indicate "unlimited"

Comment: Thank you Mathias, this was exactly what I was looking for :)